# Insert from stored procedure completing but not inserting

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, insert, try-catch

This code looks like it's going to work for me, but then it doesn't.

```
ALTER PROC dbo.spInsertNewVendor
AS
BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRAN
            INSERT INTO Vendors (VendorID, VendorName, Address, City, State, ZipCode, Active)
            VALUES (1002, 'Appleburg', '1472 Witch Hollow Way', 'Salt Lake City', 'Utah', 84115, 'TRUE')
            COMMIT TRAN
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRAN
        END CATCH
END

EXEC dbo.spInsertNewVendor
```

I've altered the stored procedure and everything went fine, but then when I executed the procedure, it didn't insert any rows like I wanted it to. Is there anything different I should do? Anything I'm missing?

UPDATE:

```
Vendors
-VendorID(PK,int)
-VendorName(nvarchar)
-Address(nvarchar)
-City(nvarchar)
-State(nvarchar)
-ZipCode(int)
-Active(nvarchar)
```

Comment: can you please provide details of Vendors table schema?

Comment: Sure. I updated the question

Comment: Is VendorID is set to be auto increment? if yes then you can not set VendorID in insert statement you just have to insert data without VendorID

Answer (score 0):

```
 -- Vendor ID Is a Primary Key And You Cannot Insert Value In PK.  
      ALTER PROC dbo.spInsertNewVendor
        AS
        BEGIN
                BEGIN TRY
                    BEGIN TRAN
                    INSERT INTO Vendors ( VendorName, Address, City, State, ZipCode, Active)
                    VALUES ('Appleburg', '1472 Witch Hollow Way', 'Salt Lake City', 'Utah', 84115, 'TRUE')
                    COMMIT TRAN
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    ROLLBACK TRAN
                END CATCH
        END
        GO
        EXEC dbo.spInsertNewVendor
```

Comment: @shredded What is The Length for NVARCHAR you Assign if it's 1 it won't allow to Insert The data.

Answer (score 0):

First find out error by this:

```
alter PROC dbo.spInsertNewVendor
AS
BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRAN
            INSERT INTO Vendors (VendorID, VendorName, Address, City, State, ZipCode, Active)
            VALUES (1002, 'Appleburg', '1472 Witch Hollow Way', 'Salt Lake City', 'Utah', 84115, 'TRUE')
            COMMIT TRAN
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRAN
            SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
        END CATCH
END

EXEC dbo.spInsertNewVendor
```

And if vendorID is Identity column then above code will give you error then
try this

```
alter PROC dbo.spInsertNewVendor
AS
BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRAN
            INSERT INTO Vendors ( VendorName, Address, City, State, ZipCode, Active)
            VALUES ( 'Appleburg', '1472 Witch Hollow Way', 'Salt Lake City', 'Utah', 84115, 'TRUE')
            COMMIT TRAN
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRAN
            SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
        END CATCH
END

EXEC dbo.spInsertNewVendor
```

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your complete SQL query on my local and it is working fine, the only problem you might be facing after updating your table is that you must have assigned your VendorID column as an identity for the auto increment and in the insert procedure you are providing the value for VendorID.

I would suggest you to please clean your table after then try to execute your procedure again.

here is what I tried on my local system:
I hope the schema for my Vendors table must be like same as of yours.

```
create table Vendors
(VendorID int,
VendorName nvarchar(100),
Address nvarchar(100),
City nvarchar(100),
State nvarchar(100),
ZipCode int,
Active nvarchar(100)
CONSTRAINT PK_Cendor PRIMARY KEY (VendorID))

CREATE PROC dbo.spInsertNewVendor
AS
BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRAN
            INSERT INTO Vendors (VendorID, VendorName, Address, City, State, ZipCode, Active)
            VALUES (1002, 'Appleburg', '1472 Witch Hollow Way', 'Salt Lake City', 'Utah', 84115, 'TRUE')
            COMMIT TRAN
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRAN
        END CATCH
END

EXEC dbo.spInsertNewVendor
```

**Output:**
[image]